# How to control placement of images/title/TOC in Rmd to Word document

Tags: r, ms-word, r-markdown, knitr

I'm trying to create a report that is organized with an image at the top (but not *in* the header, so using a reference doc doesn't work), followed by a title, subtitle, another image, and a TOC starting on the second page of the document. Is this possible when knitting Rmd to Word? I've tried moving parts of the YAML header further down the document—bringing the toc part of the code down below the title/subtitle, or moving the topimage above the title/subtitle... Small changes. I haven't been able to find solutions online that are specifically for Word documents.

Right now, the code looks like this:

````
---
params:
  name:
    label: Variable Name
    value: Variable Value
    input: select
    choices: Choice
toc: yes
toc_depth: 2
theme: united
output:
  word_document:
    reference_docx: ref.docx
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo=TRUE)
    ``` 
```{r Initials, echo=FALSE, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE}

library(stars);library(dplyr);library(ggplot2);library(viridis);library(here);library(ggrepel);library(rlang);library(units);library(knitr);library(glue); library(gt); library(officer);library(officedown); library(abind); library(sf);library(shiny); library(here); library(data.table); library(lubridate); library(openxlsx); library(tidyr); library(raster);library(sp)

    ```
    ```{r values, include=FALSE}
# Run R Script
SiteID = params$name
source("Script.R", local = knitr::knit_global())
    ```
    ---
    title: "Title Here"
    subtitle: "Subtitle Here"
    ---
    ```{r imagenames, echo=FALSE, out.width='90%'}
    topimage <- paste0("top_image.png")
    cover <- paste0("cover_image.jpg")
    knitr::include_graphics(topimage)
    knitr::include_graphics(cover)
    ```
````